# Emoji List Command Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I created an emoji list command here is my code of the command:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "emojis",
    description: "Gets a guild\'s emojis",

    async run (client, message, args) {
 const emojis = [];
    message.guild.emojis.cache.forEach(e => emojis.push(`${e} **-** \`:${e.name}:\``));
 const embed = new MessageEmbed()  
    .setTitle(`Emoji List`)
    .setDescription(emojis.join('\n'))
    message.channel.send(embed)
  }
};
```

However I get this error in case the characters in the embed exceeds 2048 letters:

```
(node:211) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.description: Must be 2048 or fewer in length.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Utki-the-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:211) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:211) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Is there any way the bot can still show the emojis and there names. By using discord-menu or like that. I was unable to understand how to do that. Can you help me out? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Isn't it obvious enough that it doesn't accept more than 2048 characters in the description?

Comment: Is there any other way to show all using any method? I am asking that @TasosBu

Comment: Split it into multiple messages

Answer (score 0):

As you can probably tell by the error message, your embed description is too long. You can split your message into several parts by using `string.split()` and send each shortened string as a separate message. Here's a rudimentary example.

```js
const charactersPerMessage = 2000;
  // we're going to go with 2000 instead of 2048 for breathing room
const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache.map(e=> { return `${e} **-** \`:${e.name}:\`` }); // does virtually the same thing as forEach()
const numberOfMessages = Math.ceil(emojis.length/charactersPerMessage); // calculate how many messages we need

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                  .setTitle(`Emoji List`);

for(i=0;i<numberOfMessages;i++) {
  message.channel.send(
    embed.setDescription(emojis.slice(i*charactersPerMessage, (i+1)*charactersPerMessage))
  );
}
```

Do take note that `emojis` is now a `string` rather than an `Array`.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to do that? I'm a bit new to coding so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I've added an example. Let me know if it gives you any problems or if you need clarification.

Comment: I get this error when I run the code:


```const emojis = message.guild.emojis.cache.map(e=> return `${e} **-** \`:${e.name}:\``); 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'return'```

Comment: Sorry, that return statement should be wrapped in braces. `.map(e=> { return ... })`

Comment: I still keep getting the same error @김현진 . As I had mentioned in the question